# IndexError: list index out of range for creating new list

Tags: python, list

I'm making a list from the previous 2 lists. I have 2 lists `boxSize`, `item`. I have to make a new list `finalArray` where the `item` are repeated `boxSize times`
eg `boxSize = [3,2,1]` & `item = [1,6,4]` then I want to craete the array as `finalArray = [1,1,1,6,6,4]`

```
def maxSize(boxSize, item, truckSize):
    c = 0
    finalArray = []
    for i in range(len(boxSize)):
        for j in range(boxSize[i]):
            finalArray[c] = item[i]
            c += 1
    finalArray.sort(reverse= True)
    maxi = 0
    finalArray = finalArray[:truckSize]
    for i in range(truckSize):
        maxi += maxi + finalArray[i]
    return maxi

The error I'm getting is IndexError: list index out of range at finalArray[c] = item[i]
```

Comment: finalArray.append(item[i])

Comment: your trying to allocate an object to a list index which doesnt exist. you need to append to the list.

Comment: change `finalArray[c] = item[i]` to `finalArray.append(item[i])`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle thanks, I'm new to list so getting my concept clear and people here are a great help. Thanks again

Comment: Your question was clear and well layed out. I am not sure why anyone down voted it. Am glad you are finding helo

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I'm also new to StackOverflow and don't know what's downvoting will really do but I will try to be more clear from next time

Comment: @vbrises thanks, mate. It worked!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use append for this particular case as the list at inital level is empty

```
def maxSize(boxSize, item, truckSize):
    c = 0
    finalArray = []
    for i in range(len(boxSize)):   
        for j in range(boxSize[i]):
            finalArray.append(item[i]) 


    finalArray.sort(reverse= True)
    maxi = 0
    finalArray = finalArray[:truckSize]
    for i in range(truckSize):
        maxi += maxi + finalArray[i]
    return maxi
```

Answer (score 1):

A much cleaner way of doing this:

```
from itertools import starmap, repeat

boxSize = [3,2,1]; item = [1,6,4]
smap = starmap(repeat, zip(item, boxSize))

output = [n for rep in smap for n in rep]

>>>output

[1, 1, 1, 6, 6, 4]
```

[Zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) pairs together item and boxSize (pairwise).

[Repeat](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) is applied to each zip. So the first element of each pair is repeat the number of time specified by the second element of each pair.

[Starmap](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) applies repeat to the pairs.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `list comprehension`

**CODE:**

```
print([x for x,y in zip(item, boxSize) for _ in range(y)])
```

**OUTPUT:**

> [1, 1, 1, 6, 6, 4]

**EXPLANATION:**

*repeat `x` (from `item`) `y` (from `boxSize`) times*

Have a look into these built-ins:
[zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)
[range](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-range)
and this data structure:
[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

or if you want to use a `for` loop, for improved readability

**CODE:**

```
res = []

for n,x in enumerate(boxSize):
    res.extend([item[n]]*x)

print(res)
```

**OUTPUT:**

> [1, 1, 1, 6, 6, 4]

**EXPLANATION:**

*get the index (`n`) and the value (`x`) of each element in `boxSize`. for each `n, x` couple, generate a list with `x` repetition of the `n`th element in `item` list and extend `res` with the result*

Have a look at this built-in:
[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
this (operation on) data structures:
[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)
and check the result of:
`[42]*3`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you start by creating a list `finalArray: []` which is an empty, hence, no index-value can be called or adressed. In your nested for loops you are trying to address the first value of your list and make it equal to a given value in array `item`. This is impossible since as we said before, `finalArray` is an empty list can has no index-value that can be passed. If you wish to add values to the list that will the equal the index value of `c` then you should use append. Here's a solution:

```
import itertools
box = [3,2,1]
item = [1,6,4]

supportarray = []
finalarray = []
s_item = [str(x) for x in item]
for i in range(len(s_item)):
        supportarray.append(s_item[i]*box[i])
for i in range(len(supportarray)): 
    finalarray.append([int(f) for f in supportarray[i]])
finalarray = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(finalarray))
print(finalarray)
```

Output: [1,1,1,6,6,4]